# Wine Questions (Rosetta Stone)

Tags: wine

I just got Rosetta Stone and was wondering how compatible it is with Wine. And whether or not it would only work when installed on Windows/Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Check Wine's application compatibility database: http://appdb.winehq.org/